# Cannot uninstall Python from homebrew

Tags: macbook-pro, homebrew, python

`which -a python3`

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3 
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 
/usr/local/bin/python3 
/usr/bin/python3
```

I want to uninstall the Python from homebrew and want to keep the default one or want to install it from the official website.

But I cannot do this, whenever I run this command 
 `brew uninstall python`
It gives me : `Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have used `brew`, you may have several Python versions, since some other bottles may need different versions. Check your installation with `brew list` and you may find out the `python@3.10` or `python@3.9`, and decide what to uninstall, but using the real name as is in list. You may check dependencies with `brew deps --tree --installed`.

Answer (score 3):

As the package is called python3, try:

```
brew uninstall python3
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You must run something like the command below. For example, if you want to uninstall python version 3.11

```
brew uninstall python@3.11
```

Comment: This isn’t significantly different from the [highest voted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/450189/119271) or any different from the [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/450192/119271) . Perhaps this should have been a comment?

Comment: I found this helpful....because I wanted a ***specific*** version of python removed, 3.11 in this case.  Before removing, I ran this to see what versions I had: ```ls -la /usr/local/bin/ | grep python```.  Then I removed some dependencies which I'll re-isntall later: ```brew uninstall pre-commit``` and ```brew uninstall virtualenv```.  Finally, I removed the version of python I no longer needed: ```brew uninstall python@3.11`` and I re-ran the ls command to verify. All is good. :)